# How to resolve "Error code: sec_error_invalid_algorithm"?

Tags: linux, operating-system, centos, yum, nss

```
I am failed to load Google in my Firefox and getting the following error :
```

1. error

   Secure Connection Failed.
   An error occurred during a connection to WWW.Google.com.
   security library: invalid algorithm.
   **  (Error code: sec_error_invalid_algorithm)**

   - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received 
     data could not be verified.
   - Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem. Alternatively, use the 
     command found in the help menu to report this broken site.

     This problem came after i had tried to install Google chrome.I am using centos6.
     How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and it is mentioned for CentOS. Please see the url :- http://osdir.com/ml/centos/2013-11/msg00670.html

It would be better if you can use firefox only or try to use an alternative old version of chrome compatible with CentIS.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: If I uninstall firefox from my system and installing another version will solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue after installing Skype v4.3 on a Centos 6.4 system. Seems the issue was the lack of nss-softokn* and nss-softokn-freebl* packages.

You can check if theses packages are installed with:

```
rpm -qa | grep nss-softokn
```

You can install the packages like so:

```
yum install nss-softokn*
```

Comment: I have tried with your first command suggestion and got result as nss-softokn-3.14.3-18.el6_6.x86_64
nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-3.el6_4.x86_64
nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-3.el6_4.i686
But the same problem remains there